# What will be the type of user in case of SCRUM story for an API?

Tags: scrum, jira-agile

I have two queries related to SCRUM. They are as follows:

1. I have read that the format of SCRUM story is "As a < type of user >, I want < some goal > so that < some reason >". I have to write a story for an API. This API will send an email with a link to validate the email address of the user. What will be the type of user here? Will it be the user logged in?
2. Do subtasks have story format similar to a story or it can be a normal description?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trouble you are encountering is likely that you are starting from a determined implementation and then trying to work backwards to the need (unless your product is an API that your users leverage, in which case I think that answers your questions).

When we approach it from a user need, we'll usually end up with more of a problem statement, like

> "As a vacationer, I'd like the site to calculate the best route across
>   all types of transportation for me so that I don't have to run many
>   searches to figure it out myself."

One of the pieces of delivering on this need will be creating the API calls if your application architecture calls for that. Then "add API method for aggregated call" may be a task under that user story.

You will have cases where all a particular story needs is API work, and that's fine, but it won't come out in the user story. For example, let's say we did the about user story but limited it to planes and trains for the first start, then we created another story that reads:

> "As a vacationer in the US, I want my trip planner to factor in buses
>   so that I can make use of bus tours in my vacation."

Now, maybe the only task in there is to create a some API changes to include the bus routes in the search, but that doesn't cause a problem with your user stories because we started back at the user's problem statement in the beginning instead of starting at the desired implementation and working backward.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start clarifying some concepts first.

Scrum is not an acronym so is written as Scrum (proper name). Then, there is nothing called "Scrum Stories". What you are referring to is called: user story. User stories were wide used in the Chrysler C3 project were eXtreme Programming was developed. Furthermore, you are referring to a particular template which was popularized by Mike Cohn known as canonical form. So it's ok to express your Product Backlog Item as user stories for an API. But take into account that you can use this template, you can use user stories or you can write the Product Backlog Item the way has more sense and value to you. In your case, which is the persona, machine or service which will be used the API?

About your second question. The [Scrum Guide](https://scrumguides.org/scrum-guide.html) just says you should decompose your Sprint Planning in unit of work of 1 day or less. Normally, the implementation is to create this unit of work and call them task which are the work necessary to carry out the user story. The way the are written is open too but is not quite common to write them in the canonical form. So you can write it as an ID, title and a description.

Comment: Add a link to [The Scrum Guide](https://scrumguides.org/scrum-guide.html).